# Can anyone explain what policy-driven is?

Tags: linux, virtualization

I read some info about copy data management

Some websites said the CDM has the following term.

> Policy-driven orchestration is the automation of the copy data
>   lifecycle, ideally through a drag-and-drop interface that makes
>   creating and modifying data workflows (or templates) an easy and
>   intuitive process.

It said the policy-driven orchestration and said that make the copy and modify data automatically.

I don't understand the term policy-driven, can anybody explain?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please don't simply link to the relevant information; include the essential elements of the link directly in your question.

Comment: @Ramhound I fix it. That's cuz it didn't give an example and I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Policy-Based automation is the process of using policies to control systems.

The idea here is to have software which check the state of the system and if it varies bring it back to a required state.  This paradyme is often used by larger organisations to control their systems.    There are a number of ways of doing this - popular systems in the Linux / Server space include Puppet, Chef and Ansible.   There are similar systems for desktops as well.

These programs check to see that services are running and configured according to a defined set of rules, and if not, try and bring the service back into policy and/or notify appropriate people so there can be manual intervention.

Answer (score 0):

policy-driven is an administrative approach that is used to simplify the management of a given endeavor by establishing policy to deal with situations that are likely to occur

policy are operating rules that can be referred to as a way to maintain folder, consistency, or mission.

Like you define a schedule to let your machine(ex: NAS) to do backup or taking snapshots.

In some NAS machine, we can schedule the backup and let it do the backup function automatically.

Also the service level agreements(SLA) is the same with policy-driven. You can set access control of some user and define what data he/she can access.